# spring datetime output

Tags: datetime, spring-roo

I have this project in spring roo wherein there's a datetime field. The date format is Short while the time format is Medium. The output for the date is ok however the time output is always showing 12:00:00 AM. It doesn't change.
Any help?
Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(style = "MS")
private Date endDate;
```

then it's showing 12:00 a.m. because date is whatever the date but no time has been set up.

Make sure your object has a time component, you can try with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy HH:mm").format(yourdateobject)
```